# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 5

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un error en mi codigo php y, no encuentro la solución este es el error gracias por tomarse su tiempo Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 5

este es el codigo

```
 include('valietc/conex.php');

 $name = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['name']));
 $last = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['apellido']));
 $user = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['username']));
 $iden = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['ci']));
 $phone = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['te']));
 $email = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['email']));
 $address = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['dire']));
 $contra = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['pass']));
 
 if(isset($_POST["butt"]))
{
    $sqlgrabar = "INSERT INTO usuario(username,password,nombre,apellido,identificacion,especialidad,telefono,correo,direccion)
    values ('$name','$last','$user','$iden','$phone','$email','$address','$contra')";
    
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sqlgrabar))
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado con exito: $nombre'); window.location='index.html' </script>";
    }else 
    {
        echo "Error: ".$sqlgrabar."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal y como el error lo dice: Error de sintaxis, inesperado ';', esperando ')'

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')'

El error esta diciéndote que te hace falta un cierre de paréntesis, por lo que debes revisar las líneas a ver en donde falta ese símbolo.

```
 $name = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['name']));
 $last = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['apellido']));
 $user = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['username']));
 $iden = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['ci']));
 $phone = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['te']));
 $email = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['email']));
 $address = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['dire']));
 $contra = remove_junk($db->escape($_POST['pass']));
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responde corregí lo que dijiste y sigue igual **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 5**

Comment: Lo hice y sigue igual

Comment: Lo hice y sale, Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 5

Comment: listo disculpa :D

Comment: Pusiste mal los parentesis, mira como te los deje yo, y como los tienes tu....

Comment: Así como lo puse arriba?

Comment: Te sigue apareciendo algún error ahora ?

Comment: Si 
**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function remove_junk() in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\clinica\valire.php on line 5**

Comment: Perfecto!! tu problema original fue solucionado. El de ahora es que la funcion `remove_junk` no existe. Este error es diferente al original, por lo que debes crear una nueva pregunta y marcar esta como solucionada. Además, puedes probar borrando esa funcion primero.

Comment: Lo cambio a `($_POST)`?

Comment: Como te dije, es otro problema ahora, por lo que debes iniciar una nueva pregunta para el. Y recuerda marcar mi respuesta como la correcta.

Comment: Disculpa como marco tu respuesta?

Comment: Debe haber un boton debajo de los votos, donde puedes marcar la respuesta como la correcta.

Comment: listo ;D gracias